# Importing Google Calendar tasks

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm building a calendar service with php (code igniter framework) and would like to import google calendar from my users.

Anyone could show me the light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use their REST interface. Almost everything you need is covered on this page:

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/getting_started.html#REST

There is a PHP client for GData on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/):

Examples can be found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html).